# how to query two tables and return NULL if a record is not in the 2nd table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, multiple-tables

I'm running `MySQL 5.0.88` and need to select data from two tables, called `articles` and `media`.

When uploading images to my server I need to query all articles of a user and see whether there is already a path specified in the media table (field `type="img"`) to avoid running unnecessary overwrites.

I had hoped to just include the `m.type` in my query, but I can't get it to work.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.style, a.filename, a.path, m.type
    FROM articles AS a
    LEFT JOIN mnedia AS m
       ON a.iln = m.iln
    WHERE
       a.iln = id_12345
       AND m.type = "img"
       AND m.type IS NOT NULL
```

This gives me ALL articles (correct) of user id_12345, but the `type` field is alway `img` although the media table only has one record for article `abc`.

**Question**:
How do I need to query, so it returns all articles of a user (working) displaying `type=NULL` for articles, which are NOT listed in table `media` and `type="img"` for articles, which are listed in the table `media`(such as `abc`)?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT**:
table `articles` may include records:

```
abc 
d
e
f
g
```

table `media` may include

```
abc type=img
```

the query should return:

```
abc type=img
d type=NULL
e type=NULL
f type=NULL
g type=NULL
```

**EDIT**:
I also woudn't mind getting all records in `articles` that are not in `media`, such as on [this](http://www.theprogrammersguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/mysql-join-qery-subquery.jpg) image, 2nd join left hand side ("b.Key IS NULL)

**SOLUTION:**
Ok. I needed to check for another field besiders user_id when joining both tables. This is how it works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.style, a.filename, a.path, m.type
    FROM articles AS a
    LEFT JOIN mnedia AS m
       ON a.iln = m.iln
       AND a.style= m.style
    WHERE
       a.iln = id_12345
       AND ( m.type = "img" OR m.type IS NULL )
```

THANKS ALL for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put `m.type = "img"` condition on `LEFT JOIN` instead of putting it in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.style, a.filename, a.path, m.type
FROM articles AS a
     LEFT JOIN mnedia AS m
         ON a.iln = m.iln
            AND m.type = "img"
WHERE a.iln = id_12345;
```

Comment: tried this, but it doesn't work. I'm still getting all records with every record having "img" specified, whereas only ABC should have "img" and all other records should have NULL or empty string or...?

Comment: that really should not happen
are you sure that the mnedia table has no entries where type="img" is set for the other articles?

Comment: just found the solution. The left join on user_id only was the problem, because I was in fact checking for the style number of a user being in the media table. See my solution above

Answer (score 1):

i think just adapting your where clause a bit, should be enough:

```
WHERE
       a.iln = id_12345
       AND (
              m.type = "img"
              OR m.type IS NULL
           )
```

Since "img" and NULL are the two values you're looking for